# gunicorn static files not found

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm building a REST Api in Django. 
I'm launching it with Gunicorn, but I have the following when I go to the admin page :

```
Not Found: /static/admin/css/dashboard.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/fonts.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/dashboard.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
Not Found: /favicon.ico
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

And the same for Rest Framework CSS files.

I tried to run "python3 manage.py collectstatic",  I effectively have a "static" folder , but I have the same problem.

In my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

Is there any way to have CSS served by Gunicorn ?

Comment: That is not what gunicorn is for. gunicorn is a WSGI server. You would normally use it with nginx as a reverse proxy, and nginx is what should be serving the static files.